# New pages not included in main navigation but display in sidebar

Tags: navigation

I have recently inherited this website and was made aware of an issue where new pages that are added to the main navigation are only displaying in the sidebar. I have followed the steps for adding pages to the main navigation, but have been unsuccessful. I have also attempted to add a page that I created myself, but it only appears in the sidebar and not in the main navigation. I have cleared the cache for both the site and database, but the issue persists.

I have searched Google for a solution, but haven't found any relevant answers. I also couldn't find anyone else experiencing the same problem, so I am reaching out to you for help. I have attached screenshots of the page setups, menu setup, and block setup. Please let me know if you require further information or if I need to provide more details about the issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[image: Menu Settings]

[image: Block Settings]

[image: Catalog Page Settings]

[image: Honors Page Settings]

[image: Main Navigation Results]

[image: Sidebar Navigation Settings]

[image: Entire Block Layout]

Comment: Are you certain the sidebar menu and the main navigation actually are the same menu? Did you rebuild caches? Are there any menu-related modules in the site? Is there any theme code modifying menu display?

Comment: The side bar and main are the same menu and the caches have been rebuilt. No modules, straight out of the box and from what I can tell there has been no code modification.

Comment: The Menu Block module is not in use?

Comment: @cilefen the block layout is.. interesting. Updated my post with a screenshot of it.

Comment: The "Menu Block" module (this is not a core module) would make short work of this (without needing umpteen blocks). Are those all really their own menus?

Comment: Annnd I'm a muppet. I was only adding it to the sidebar menu and NOT the primary menu. Thank you to @cilefen for asking me a good question that made me start digging around and being able to resolve the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin, sadly yes and that was the root of my problem. I've added "Menu block" to the list of implementations to make life easier. Thanks for the answer mate.